# rails serving static asset path which doesn't match precompiled manifest

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nginx, unicorn

I've tried reading through many other questions on how to properly configure nginx to serve static assets for rails 3.2 but no matter what I attempt the asset path being loaded by my browser does not match the asset version specified in manifest.yml after precompile and as a result all my assets are not found.

My nginx config is as follows:

```
location ~ ^/assets/ {    

    # Per RFC2616 - 1 year maximum expiry
    # http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html
    expires 1y;
    add_header Cache-Control public;

    gzip_static on;

    # Some browsers still send conditional-GET requests if there's a
    # Last-Modified header or an ETag header even if they haven't
    # reached the expiry date sent in the Expires header.
    add_header Last-Modified "";
    add_header ETag "";
    break;
}
```

I've also checked the root path in nginx is correct. I'm using nginx with unicorn via a Unix Domain Socket.

First time I set this up everything loaded fine. Then I modified an asset and re-deployed. That asset was then broken. I then bumped the asset version and now all assets are broken. I've tried clearing my local cache in case that was causing problems but it didn't help.

I'm starting to tear my hair out at this point, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After more investigation I found the unicorn process wasn't properly restarting when updating.